# php chain calling static non objects

Tags: php, reflection, static

I can make infinite calling by returning `$this` in class body functions after creating as object. 
Is it possible to make the same without creating object? 
Something like `myclass::func1()::func2()::func3()` 
i was trying with reflection and stored new class in parent variable, but it returning also object, which couldnt be called by `::`

Comment: Late static binding is your friend. If you're free to use PHP 5.3, then that's the way to go if you need that kind of functionality.

Comment: I use it as helper classes by autoloader ofc, and i was trying to rewrite my templating shell as static too, but..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to chain static methods.

Comment: Very sadly, maybe i should use created class as shell to calling throught it static classes? Or it would be the same like put static funcs into that shell?

Comment: @Jacob88: static functions are not different than normal functions. Procedural code at its finest. It's usually best to avoid them, given the fact the PHP supports both functions and namespaces.

Comment: T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM - see http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/5127.htm :) you cant, no - i think reason is, that PHP handles static class method referencing, statically only. You cannot use 'self' as reference to call a method in static memoryspace